# Prevent Data Source Prompt in Excel When Not Available

Tags: excel, odbc, vba

I have an Excel file that has multiple ODBC data connections in it.  Users can open this in two different ways.  Either on the server, which the connection works and should run, and on their desktop where the connection cannot run.  I have set the connection to only run when on the server but despite not running it on the desktop, a data source prompt always pops up.  How can I prevent the data source prompt from opening on the desktop?

Here is the code that I use:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

On Error Resume Next
If Application.OperatingSystem = "Windows (32-bit) NT 6.01" Then
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End If

Worksheets("New").Select
Range("J4").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: did you try application.displayalerts = false?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't prevent it. @AshtonMorgan